# Removing WordPress users via SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a bunch of WordPress users that I'd like removed in the wp_users table. The query I want to run  is:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_users` WHERE `user_registered` > '2010-08'
```

However, there are also a crap load of rows I want removed from wp_usermeta, where the column `user_id` matches the above query. How can I delete the related rows in wp_usermeta at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM `wp_usermeta`
WHERE `wp_users`.`user_registered` > '2010-08'
      AND `wp_users`.`user_id` = `wp_usermeta`.`user_id`
```

Replace user_id according your database schema

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work. I did a SELECT to see what the results looked like. 

`SELECT * FROM wp_usermeta, wp_users WHERE `wp_users`.`user_registered` > '2010-08' AND `wp_users`.`ID` = `wp_usermeta`.`user_id``

Comment: I ended up doing it a few queries. I found from my original query that the user id > 1480 for users created after 2010-08. Then I just used this to delete all rows in wp_usermeta..

Comment: What's the syntax error in here? I've replaced the backticks with single quotes, but still hitting errors.